# EF 6 Code First Related Entities Not Saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a very simple data structure of a `Person` that has related `Addresses`. Using code first, I retrieve the person, get their primary address, update it and save, but the changes are not persisted to the DB.

```
address = person.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.IsPrimary == true);
address.Line1 = line1;
person.LastName = lastName;

_db.People.Attach(person);
_db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

In this case the LastName property is saved in the DB because it is a property on the person itself, but the address Line 1 is on a related entity and it does not get saved. Is there some trick to getting the related entities to save?

Comment: I think you need to specify that the address object is also modified - `EntityState.Modified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I need to set each related entity to modified. This works actually but I thought that setting the parent object to the modified state should take care of it but apparently not. So that means if I have ten related objects and I am updating them all, then I need to set the state for all of them.

```
_db.Entry(person.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.IsPrimary)).State = EntityState.Modified;
```